# How to tell if a commit belongs to a local project

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Let's say we have two sessions -sessionOne and sessionTwo.
I used sessionOne two create an initial project that has two commits and push this project to github remote:

[image]

Then I (as another user) use sessionTwo to clone this Github repository to local and then I modify a file and create a commit locally:

[image]

Then I switch to seesionOne and create a third commit then push change to remote:

[image]

Now I switch to sessionTwo and pull from the remote, since I (on behalf of another user ) made changes on existing on seesionTwo before, there is confilct and so I fix the conflict and git adds a merge change, then I push changes to remote as:
[image]

Now my question is, when I use sessionOne to do `git pull`, I gets a same output which is very similar to above:

[image]

the "modify sth" commit is originally from sessionTwo, but in sessionOne's
Sourcetree output, it is colored in blue, after long time, I might think this is the change I made after a long time when I quickly look at the graph.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Your last sentence is confusing because you did make that change. Do you want it to show someone else made it? Note the graph usually shows the author name as well, and in this case they would both be you, unless you used a different user name in "session two". What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: In the most reduced sense, a commit "belongs" to a local checkout (not project) if it doesn't exist in any other checkouts of the same git repository, but even this is a confused way of looking at it. If you need to work out who created the commit, then you can look at the author (as @TTT has mentioned).

Comment: A commit exists in a repository if the hash ID of the commit exists in the repository's object database and has type "commit". Hash IDs are globally unique, across *all* repositories. Cloning a repository essentially copies all of its commits (and none of its branches, normally); `git fetch` and `git push` are how you send commits between two repositories, so that they become shared. The commit's hash ID *is* the commit, in a sense, although you need to have the commit (stored under that hash ID) to use it.

Comment: Branch names like `master`, and remote-tracking names like `origin/master`, are per-repository *labels:* each one is attached to *one specific commit* and helps you find that commit. A commit then finds any *earlier* ("parent") commit, because each commit contains a list of parent commit hash IDs, usually just one entry long.

Comment: Normally, when you clone some existing repository, your Git takes their repository's branch names (`master`) and *renames* those to your `origin/*` names. So what were branch names in their repository are now remote-tracking names in yours. You have all the commits, and none of the branches. Then your cloning Git makes one *new* branch name, of your choice: you pick which branch you want from the remote-tracking names you got by renaming their branch names, and your Git creates a branch name with the `origin/` removed again.

Comment: A subsequent `git fetch` goes to the repository you cloned, lists out their branch names and hash IDs, finds any new commits they have that you don't, gathers those commits from them, and then updates your remote-tracking names. So now your `origin/*` names remember their branch name hash IDs again.

Comment: `git push` is the oddball here: your `git push` sends new commits that you have, that they don't, to the other Git repository ... but then it asks *them* to update one of their *branch names*, to remember the new commit. There's no remote-tracking name involved here: your Git just asks them to set *their* `master`, or whatever branch name you use.

Comment: In the end, though, all the Git repositories have all the commits, and as far as they are concerned, those are THEIR commits and THEY are the master of everything. Every other Git repository is just a mere "other Git repository", good only for getting new commits from. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commits don't "belong" to any particular repo, whether that repo is the origin, upstream, some other remote or a local clone. Git does not explicitly track which repo introduced the commit. The things git tracks for each commit are:

1. the commit hash
2. the state of all the files in the repo as of that commit.
3. it's parent commit(s)
4. the commit author
5. the committer
6. the author date
7. the commit date
8. the commit message

There might be some other things I missed, but there is nothing about which repo the commit came from.

> Note: The commit message *might* include information about which remote repo or git client the commit was pushed from, e.g. the `Merge branch 'master' from...` message in your example above, but that was added by GitHub, not by git, and won't be there if the merge was done directly, not through GitHub's interface.

You wrote "I might think this is the change I made", which means you are concerned about *who* made the changes. In that case, the commit author as well as the committer are tracked, as I listed above.

The author and the committer are usually the same, but differ when, for example, you, the author, commit a change and make a pull request. When the pull request is accepted, you will remain the author, but the person who accepts the pull request will be tracked as the committer for the commit that results from the pull request.